# Display only the users in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, cut

I'm trying to display only the users' name from a downloaded file in Linux named *users.csv*. The format of file is users; /home/directory.
I tried the following:

```
cut -d: -f1 users.csv
```

And also

```
awk -F: '{printf $1}' users.csv
```

None of them works. After enter home directory shows too.

Comment: The last sentence is incomprehensible. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66171373/edit)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66171373/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Since the field delimiter is ";" and not ":", you need to specify it in the commands and so:

```
cut -d\; -f1 users.csv

awk -F\; '{ print $1 }' users.csv
```